# mySql join - multiple records from same table

Tags: sql, join

Im looping through a list of forum posts, pulling the data from 2 tables, `posts` and `members`.

I'm using a `LEFT JOIN` like

`SELECT m.name, p.title FROM posts LEFT JOIN members m ON p.poster=m.id`

That all works fine. But I also need to pull a different record from the members table, that of the `p.lastposter`. How would I do this? I can't add another JOIN in there can I because i'm already pulling a `m.name` and wouldn't it confuse it?

Answer (score 3):

You can add another join with a different alias:

```
SELECT m.name, p.title, lp.name AS lastposter 
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN members AS m ON p.poster=m.id
LEFT JOIN members AS lp ON p.lastposter = lp.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 different `rows` you may use `UNION`:

```
SELECT m.name, p.title FROM posts LEFT JOIN members m ON p.poster=m.id

UNION

SELECT m.name, p.title FROM posts LEFT JOIN members m ON p.lastposter=m.id
```

---

If you want more info on the same `row` from `lastposter` do this:

```
SELECT m.name, p.title, lp.name AS lastposter 
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN members AS m ON p.poster=m.id
LEFT JOIN members AS lp ON p.lastposter = lp.id
```

Comment: thanks, I've done the 2nd method but getting an error when I add a LIMIT on the end. I want to limit the records it finds from `posts`

Comment: You'd probably want UNION ALL here, no?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't add another JOIN in there can I because i'm already pulling a m.name and wouldn't it confuse it?

No.

```
SELECT m.name, p.title, lastpostMembers.name AS lastpostername FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN members m ON p.poster=m.id
LEFT JOIN members lastpostMembers ON p.lastposter=lastpostMembers.id
```

I really don't see why you're left joining here though; seems like you really want an inner join.